# Как в ActionBar принудительно сделать чтобы появилось меню справа

Tags: android

Как в `ActionBar` принудительно сделать чтобы появилось меню справа?

А то после обнов SDK перестала появляться 3 точки справа

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такой вариант

```
try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
        menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
    } catch (Exception ex) {}
```

Типо выключить проверку.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нужен атрибут у итема `android:showAsAction="never"`

например:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:alphabeticShortcut="r"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh_white_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Видимо вы меня не поняли. Попробуйте скачать Api 21 и меню создать запустите на телефону с кнопкой меню. Увидите о чем я говорю, такое не прокатит, уже.

Comment: Ну так что?, эта фигня появилась после ToolBar!